# How to run PhantomJS on Pivotal Cloud Foundry?

Tags: phantomjs, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I have downloaded the phantomjs binary and have added it to the root directory. However, when I deploy the application to PCF, the phantomjs binary is not getting uploaded. Is there a phantomjs buildpack available for PCF? How can I run phantomJS on PCF?

```
executable_path='./phantomjs'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path)
```

Comment: What makes you say it's not getting uploaded?

Comment: What kind of application (and so buildpack) are you using?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta The phantomjs file is close to 60MB  - only my application gets uploaded which is of 3 MB